# Non-symmetric keychord

Tags: key-bindings, key-chord-mode

I currently have this in my init file `(key-chord-define-global "xf" 'find-file)`. Actually, `xf` and `fx` will trigger the `find-file` function. In fact, whatever the keychord I defined, it works whatever the order in which keys are pressed. So, just want to know if this is a normal behaviour, and if there is there a way to avoid `fx` to be considered as a keychord.

Comment: Key-chord bindings should be thought of as "two keys pressed at the same time", so order doesn't matter by design.

Comment: @glucas Thanks, I understand, having the possibility to set `key-chord-two-keys-delay` is not really suggesting an idea of "pressed at same time", then, made me think the order could matter.

Comment: Agreed. The delay is intended as a margin of error , I think. But with a slightly longer delay you could imagine having different bindings for different orders. I'm not aware of any way to configure that.

Comment: If you'd like to bind only a specific sequence, you should check out https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra. That package can be used to create 'temporary modes'. You could potentially bind `x` to start a hydra that binds `f` to your desired action and times out after a moment. Hydras can be configued so that keys not specifically bound keep their default behavior and exit the hydra -- there are a number of posts on http://oremacs.com that explain this better. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the source for `key-chord.el`, when you add a binding for `xf` it is explicitly creating two bindings, one for `xf` and one for `fx`.

Just because this is the standard doesn't mean you have to adhere to it. You can modify the code that does this to only do one binding.

You'll just need to take a line out of `key-chord-define`.

Here is the function, and the line to remove:

```lisp
(defun key-chord-define (keymap keys command)
  (if (/= 2 (length keys))
      (error "Key-chord keys must have two elements"))
  (let ((key1 (logand 255 (aref keys 0)))
        (key2 (logand 255 (aref keys 1))))
    (if (eq key1 key2)
        (define-key keymap (vector 'key-chord key1 key2) command)
      (define-key keymap (vector 'key-chord key1 key2) command)
      ;; just remove this line:
      (define-key keymap (vector 'key-chord key2 key1) command))))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice, let's not adhere to the standard.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, you may be able to achieve what you want using a different package like [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra). Here is an example that binds `find-file` to the key sequence `x f` with no modifiers.

```
(require 'hydra)

(defun x-hydra-pre ()
  (insert "x")
  (hydra-timeout 0.5))

(defhydra x-hydra (:body-pre x-hydra-pre
                   :color blue
                   :hint nil)
  ("f" (progn (zap-to-char -1 ?x) (ido-find-file))))

(global-set-key "x" #'x-hydra/body)
```

With this configuration, the key sequence <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (with no modifiers) will call `ido-find-file`. Typing an x followed by anything else will behave normally, and if you really need to type "xf" you can hit <kbd>x</kbd> and wait half a second for the hydra to time out before hitting the <kbd>f</kbd>.

So what's happening here:

- <kbd>x</kbd> is globally bound to enable a hydra, which sets up a temporary key map.
- The hydra has a `:body-pre` hook which runs when the hydra body is invoked. In this case it inserts an "x" and starts a timeout timer.
- The hydra's temporary key map binds <kbd>f</kbd> to delete the "x" that was just inserted and instead find a file.
- Any other key will exit the hydra and perform its normal action so you can just keep typing.
- When the 0.5 second timer elapses, the hydra exits so its temporary key bindings go away.

(Note that at the time I tested this I had an error with hydra timeout support, but there is a fix available.)

Comment: This doesn't do the timeout thing though which makes it feel pretty awkward for normal typing, the other problem is that it gets weird once you do more than one such combination.

Comment: Agreed, just offering an alternative. With this approach you could make x a prefix for all sorts of commands and still type an x when necessary using xx. See also https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/issues/34 re: timeout support.

Comment: Perhaps a better key to abuse this way is `q`, since it must almost always be followed by a `u` (in English). So make `q` start a hydra where `u` inserts `qu`; then make whatever other bindings you need. :)

Comment: @glucas given that timeouts are now supported (yay!), could you extend the answer to include them?

Comment: @PythonNut I'd like to, but I'm having some issues with hydra's timeout support. I just submitted a pull request for one problem, but it seems like there is something else that isn't behaving as I'd expect...

Comment: @glucas Ah. Noted.

Comment: @PythonNut Ah, got it to work. In this example hydra I'm binding a key to the body, and hydra doesn't start the timer until a head is invoked. But calling `hydra-timeout` in a `:body-pre` works. So if my other fix gets merged in I'll update this example to show how it works.

Comment: I've revised the example to use hydra's timeout support, and it seems to work quite nicely. Note that depending on your Emacs version you may need this hydra fix: https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/commit/88c7dc41cf28d263c03532904e9a8727a6455d48

Comment: This needs some tweaking to be useful: mainly, need to check if the buffer is read-only before trying to insert/ delete the x. Might be better to use a :post hook instead so you aren't modifying the buffer when you find a file.

Answer (score 5):

To get help with a function in emacs, type `C-h f <function name>`. In your case, e.g. `key-chord-mode`. This doesn't give you much info regarding your specific question, but the help buffer will contain a link to the file where the function is defined, in this case `key-chord.el`. In this file there is documentation in the comments at the beginning of the file, containing:

```
;; ########   Terminology   ########################################
;;
;; In this package, a "key chord" is two keys pressed simultaneously,
;; or a single key quickly pressed twice.
;;
```

And further down:

```
;; ########   Tips   ########################################
;;
...
;; Grep your own texts to verify that a combination is unusual.
;; And don't forget to check both permutations: "fg" and "gf".
```